# protege how to use instances from ontology on the web

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology, protege

In my ontology i have an instances named `beethoven`, how can I say that my `beethoven` instance is the same as this beethoven

http://dbpedia.org/page/Ludwig_van_Beethoven

I know that I have to use owl:sameAs predicate, but the thing is when I click on sameAs predicate, protege just give me a list of already existing instances. However, I'm asking about an instance from an ontology on the web.

What I was thinking of is maybe I have to import that ontology, but thing about it, if i want to sue dbpedia, do i really have to import the whole dbpedia to my machine?

Im sure there is something easier and that's why I'm asking you guys

Thanks in advance

#### Update 1

After reading this answer

[Extend DBpedia entity in Protege ontology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703414/extend-dbpedia-entity-in-protege-ontology)

I created an instance of the type **THINKG** in my protege and gave it the exact same URI (which is http://dbpedia.org/page/Ludwig_van_Beethoven ), and said that my beethoven instance is owl:sameAs this new instance, would that be enough?

#### Update2

I tried to query my ontology after the things that I have listed in **update1**, and I noticed this:

this query:

```
select ?z where 
{
    mo:Beethoven owl:sameAs ?z
}
```

returns empty result

However, this query:

```
select ?z where 
{
    dbpedia:Ludwig_van_Beethoven owl:sameAs ?z
}
```

returns **my beethoven instance** like this:
[image]

how can the dbpedia:beethoven is the same as mo:beethoven, but the other way around, **knowing that I said mo:beethoven is owl:sameAs dbpedia:beethoven** not the other way around

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the important differences between RDF and OWL.  RDF is just a bunch of triples.  The triples:

```
:LVBeethoven owl:sameAs :LudwigVanBeethoven
```

and

```
:LudwigVanBeethoven owl:sameAs :LVBeethoven
```

are different triples.  RDF graphs are just sets of triples.

OWL, on the other hand, is a *logic*, concerned with axioms and inferences.  owl:sameAs is the equality predicate for OWL individuals, and equality predicates are symmetric (among other things).  That means that from  **A owl:sameAs B** an OWL reasoner can *infer* that **B owl:sameAs A**.  So, if you have a reasoner attached to your SPARQL endpoint, you'll be able to query for either **A owl:sameAs ?x** or **?x owl:sameAs A** and get **B** as a result.  You can do some limited forms of OWL reasoning in SPARQL.  In this case, you could use a property path to follow an **owl:sameAs** link in either direction:

```sql
select ?z where 
{
    mo:Beethoven (owl:sameAs|^owl:sameAs) ?z
}
```

For some more examples, see [Using SPARQL for limited RDFS and OWL reasoning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474862/using-sparql-for-limited-rdfs-and-owl-reasoning).